# How does UFT perform the Click method when using the Web Add In?

Tags: javascript, qtp, hp-uft

I am testing a highly javascript based application on Internet Explorer 8.0 with UFT 11.50. I would like to know how UFT implements the "Click" method under the hood when using the Web Add In. Does UFT send a windows mouse event? Does it fire an event (onclick, onmousedown, onmouseup)? I have been seeing some mixed results with my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can do either, by default UFT replays using DOM events but you can change the replay type to device in which case it queries the HTML element's location and simulates a mouse click on that location.

The replay mode is controlled by **Tools->Opitions->Web->Advanced->RunSettings** or in the script by:

```
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2 ''# Changes to device mode
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 1 ''# Changes to event mode
```

Note that in event mode UFT doesn't just send a `click`, it sends other events that typically are used by applications (such as `focus`, `mousedown` and `mouseup`) unless the registry value **ReplayOnlyClick** in the **WebPackage** settings is set to `1`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. When UFT is in event mode, is there a certian set of events that are allows sent? Does it depend on that browser you are testing? For instance, when testing internet explorer, will UFT always send, focus, mousedown, mouseup events, in that order?

Comment: Don't forget the `click` event :) I believe that the order of events is consistent and the same for all browsers. You can write some HTML that logs the events it receives and check.

Comment: Hi @Motti, When you say "event" mode, does it mean UFT injects javascript into the application to do the click?

Comment: @sriramsridharan UFT has a browser extension that lets it interact with the web page

Comment: @Motti Thank you. Is this different from JS injection? Because the add-on finally executes JS on the web page to interact with the page if i'm not wrong.

Comment: @sriramsridharan, browser extensions have direct access to the DOM, the extension may be written in JS (for IE it can be .NET/C++). The extension may also inject JS into the page, how it works is an implementation detail that shouldn't really make any difference to you.