# How do you simulate a keyboard enter event in UFT

Tags: javascript, qtp, hp-uft

I have a web application that I am testing with HP's UFT software. Within my application, 
there is a text field with an onkeydown attribute. When a key is pressed within the text field, a function is called which triggers different actions depending on what key was pressed. I am interested in the enter key. When the enter key is pressed, rows are created within the form. How can I simulate the enter key being pressed within the field?

I have tried

`field1.Set Chr(13)`

`field1.FireEvent "onkeydown"`

but it doesn't trigger the event.

I am trying aviod using the SendKeys command.

Comment: when i press enter and alert box should pop up...i can give you a fiddle on that...?should i?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use *device replay mode* (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17703200/3848)) and send a `vbCRLF` your application will be able to see the enter key.

```
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2 ''# Changes to device mode
Browser("Enter").Page("Enter").WebEdit("WebEdit").Set  "a" & vbCRLF
```

This works (on IE) for the following sample page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Enter</title>
<script>
function okd() {
if (event.keyCode == 13)
    alert("Got enter");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea onkeydown="okd()"></textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfect. It didn't occur to me that the decive replay worked the same way for keyboard events. It makes sense now. My testing scripts will be more robust with this change. Thanks!

Comment: Are there implications to this?  I've just used it to get around a nasty enter problem which I could not solve to save my life.  Using this solves it but I wonder if I need to set the replayType back to 1 straight away after this works for me?

Comment: When you use device mode it moves your mouse so if you're trying to use the computer for something else while running a  test it will get in your way. Also if you're running the test on a remote machine with no display connected (e.g. the RDP window is minimized) then the device steps will not work. Other than that I don't know of any other implications. Arguably device mode is better for functional testing since it more accuratly mimics a real user's actions.

Answer (score 1):

These are the some methods i have tried for simulate keyboard events and worked for me..

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

oShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"           ' Click Tab Key
oShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"         ' Click Enter\Return
```

Also i have used

```
Type micAltDwn + "RETURN" + micAltUp ' Click Tab Key
Type micAltDwn + "TAB" + micAltUp    ' Click Enter\Return
```

If u Want to enter characters

```
 oShell.SendKeys "{h}"           ' Click h Key
 oShell.SendKeys "{i}"           ' Click i Key

 Type micAltDwn + "h" + micAltUp    ' Click h Key
 Type micAltDwn + "i" + micAltUp    ' Click i Key
```

Answer (score 0):

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSM6e/1/)

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
   $("#my_id").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert("Enter Simulated!!!")
       //your function goes here!!!
    }
});
    });
```

UPDATE:[2nd demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4xbUv/14/)