# How to select option from Auto suggest list in UFT 14.02?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft14

I'm new to UFT and I'm trying to select element from the Auto suggest list using Record and Play option of UFT.
this is my recorded script for auto suggest list

```
Browser("Log in to iCare").Page("iCare_3").WebEdit("Start typing your medication").Set "AMLODIPINE TAB"
Browser("Log in to iCare").Page("iCare_3").WebList("AMLODIPINE TAB").Click
```

But when I'm running it UFT just setting AMLODIPINE TAB option in text box and not selecting the option from the list so due to this I'm not redirecting to next modal view.

I have also tried SendKeys but still it is not woring

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "AMLODIPINE TAB"
wait 3
WshShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
wait 3
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
wait 3
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Please see attach screen short
[image]

Waiting for reply..thank you

Comment: Have you tried simulating Enter key after you set the data in the weblist?

Comment: After writing in the edit box, you can give a delay of say 2 seconds for the list to display items. After that delay, you can perform the click operation

Comment: @Gurman yes I have tired wait(2) after edit box but did not worked

Answer (score 1):

It may be that UFT's `WebEdit.Set` command doesn't simulate the specific events the application is looking for. In such cases using device replay usually solves this problem. See [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17920339/3848).

**tl;dr;** Try this code:

```vbs
origReplayType = Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType")
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2 ' Changes to device mode
Browser("Log in to iCare").Page("iCare_3").WebEdit("Start typing your medication").Set "AMLODIPINE TAB"
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = origReplayType ' return to previous mode

Browser("Log in to iCare").Page("iCare_3").WebList("AMLODIPINE TAB").Click
```

Comment: I tried this but only "Amlodipine tab" is getting set into text box the clicking event is not happening

Comment: @KrishnaPatel does the dropdown list appear?

Comment: No, it is not appearing at the time of running

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any other ideas

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Browser("Log in to iCare").Page("iCare_3").WebElement("Html Tag:=li","innertext:=AMLODIPINE TAB").Click
```

instead of

```
Browser("Log in to iCare").Page("iCare_3").WebList("AMLODIPINE TAB").Click
```

this might be work and if not then try it with

```
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2
```