# ExtJs - Triggering Column Header Sorting programmatically (e.g. with QTP)

Tags: sorting, extjs4, qtp, ui-automation, gridview-sorting

Our team is setting up test scripts for automating interaction testing using QTP, for an ExtJS based application.

Many of our elements/objects are being detected as desired, with the exception of column header sorting triggers.

Our grid panel has remote sorting, however programatically triggering a column header "click" doesn't fire our sorting, although "click"ing manually on the column header does. I've tried mousedown and mouseup, on the column header Div, and it's children -titleEl and -textEl as well.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to tell QTP to generate mouse events, this way all the events that are fired when a real human clicks the header will be fired when QTP clicks it.

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17703200/3848)

```
origReplayType = Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType")
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2

Browser("B").Page("P").WebElement("column header").Click ' your script line here

Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = origReplayType
```

If this is a common occurrence you can use [`RegisterUserFunc`](http://www.automationrepository.com/2011/12/understanding-registeruserfunc-syntax-with-example/) to define a new `DeviceClick` function to your test objects.

A slightly more complex way is to debug the application and see which event triggers sorting the column and then use `FireEvent` with the correct event.