# Write in textBox using .Set with UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I'm automating a web portal with Iexplorer. I am using UFT V11.50.

I'm having problems when writing to a textbox. I use the following statement:

```
Browser ("browser"). Page ("page"). Frame ("Calendar"). WebEdit ("_ CALCOD"). Set "5"
```

I use .SET to write to him textbox and it works but it is not recorded. Writes in the textbox number 5 but a second then disappears. I do not feel the same in other textbox.

I do not understand what happens to me. Can you help?

Comment: Have you tried the type() function? If that doesn't work, try adding a small wait before you type in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that your edit field responds to different HTML events than UFT uses (UFT uses the most common events).

One way to work around this is to use *device replay*, this means that UFT will simulate a human being sitting at the keyboard and simulate the actual input device of the computer, thus the browser will fire all the events it would if a real person set the value of the edit field.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17703200/3848) for more details about device replay mode.

```
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2 ' Enter device mode

Browser("browser").Page("page").Frame("Calendar").WebEdit("_CALCOD").Set "5"

Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 1 ' Return to event mode
```

Comment: I tried your answer and has also worked for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution to my problem was as follows:

```
Public function writeText(field) 
  Set x = Browser("browser").Page("page").Frame("Calendar").WebEdit("_CALCOD")
  x.Object.innertext=field  
End Function
```

> field = 5

It may be that my answer is not the most optimal, but it worked.