# vbscript sendkeys works only once after system restart

Tags: vbscript, qtp, sendkeys

I have a weird situation here and I am not able to find out the reason and fix.

I have written a script using HP UFT  11.52 for testing a .net web application on IE8

Here is the code:

```
If Browser(x).Page(x).Frame(x).WebEdit(abc).Exist(0) Then
    Browser(x).Page(x).Frame(x).WebEdit(abc).Click
    Set objSSN=Createobject("Wscript.Shell")
    objSSN.SendKeys" "
    Set objSSN=Nothing
    Browser(x).Page(x).Frame(x).WebEdit(abc).Object.Focus()
    Browser(x).Page(x).Frame(x).WebEdit(abc).Set 100-10-1000
End If
```

This code runs fine when I run the script after starting my windows laptop. If I run the same code the second time, the code will not enter the space and so does not enter the SSN. Now entering a space is required since clicking the webedit will result in a blank selection, so if I enter something with script it gives incorrect data.

My teammate who works on a virtual machine for running these scripts had no issues running this script on his machine. So I suspect there is some setting either in IE or windows somewhere which needs to be modified.

Can anyone help me identifying the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sending a space try changing the [replay type to device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17703200/3848) and then `Set` a space

```
If Browser(x).Page(x).Frame(x).WebEdit(abc).Exist(0) Then
    Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2 
    Browser(x).Page(x).Frame(x).WebEdit(abc).Set " " ' This may not be needed
    Browser(x).Page(x).Frame(x).WebEdit(abc).Set "100-10-1000"
    Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 1 
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

To enter SSN in a textbox using QTP, do we have to really do a click & focus?

Below script should be fine.

```
If Browser(x).Page(x).Frame(x).WebEdit(abc).Exist(0) Then
    Browser(x).Page(x).Frame(x).WebEdit(abc).Set "100-10-1000"
End If
```

Comment: I tried with the above code you mentioned Vinoth. But it did not work, I then tried sendkeys and entered a space, it worked.  But now the issue seems to be different, it only works for the first time after I restart windows.

Comment: When you say it does not work - what is happening exactly? I am not understanding use of `sendkeys` in your case. If you need a space in the SSN textbox, `Browser(x).Page(x).Frame(x).WebEdit(abc).Set " "` . should work too.

Comment: If i do not add a space and just set the value only then it randomly sometimes sets the value and sometimes it does not. If I manually click the field, it does not directly show the cursor blinking, instead it selects the whole webedit's empty spaces. Manually I have to click again to have the cursor displayed. If I do not repeat the exact same steps as I mentioned for the manual steps, it will not enter the data in the field. So i figured a space character would help, and it worked

Comment: Whatever the behavior you are saying  - is this how it is supposed to work?